# sed command to replace a word after another one

Tags: sed

Let's say i have a file where the word "default" is repeated more times. I want to replace it with "custom" but just where it follows the word "background", regardless of the line number. How could I achieve this with the sed command?

I have been able to do it with
`` sed - i '/set background default/c\set background custom /` file.conf `` but it's not really worth changing a whole line for just replacing a single word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, using *capture group*:

```
sed -i -E 's/(set background) default/\1 custom/' file.conf
#            ^--------------^        ^-^   
#              captured           restaured
```